# Tracking down symbols used by library in binary ELF as listed in memory map

Tags: linux, c++, crash, core-dump, elf

I have an application written in C++ that crashed during exit. The reason for the crash is understood, there are references to different versions of the same library mixed inside the executable. This is a mistake we are trying to track down so to help us do that we are hoping we can make use of the memory map dump created when the executable crashed.

These are the relevant sections of the memory map:

```
7ffff5bc7000-7ffff5ccc000 r-xp 00000000 00:38 2348051668                 /devel/utility/release/lib64/libUtils.so
7ffff5ccc000-7ffff5ecc000 ---p 00105000 00:38 2348051668                 /devel/utility/release/lib64/libUtils.so
7ffff5ecc000-7ffff5ece000 r--p 00105000 00:38 2348051668                 /devel/utility/release/lib64/libUtils.so
7ffff5ece000-7ffff5ed2000 rw-p 00107000 00:38 2348051668                 /devel/utility/release/lib64/libUtils.so
```

```
7fbbf73c3000-7fbbf73ee000 r--p 00000000 00:31 2235616792                 /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so
7fbbf73ee000-7fbbf7462000 r-xp 0002b000 00:31 2235616792                 /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so
7fbbf7462000-7fbbf747e000 r--p 0009f000 00:31 2235616792                 /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so
7fbbf747e000-7fbbf747f000 ---p 000bb000 00:31 2235616792                 /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so
7fbbf747f000-7fbbf7481000 r--p 000bb000 00:31 2235616792                 /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so
7fbbf7481000-7fbbf7483000 rw-p 000bd000 00:31 2235616792                 /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so
```

These sections show that different parts of the same executable are linked to different versions of the library on the filesystem. I have the matching core dump file as well and my question is:

Is it possible to determine which symbols in the executable code were linked at runtime to each version of the library from this memory mapping? Or maybe there is a way to do this from the executable itself?

This executable makes direct use of the code on libUtils.so but also links other libraries that themselves may use libUtils.so. It is our guess that one of these is linking to the v6.6 instance instead of the release instance and we are trying to track it down.

An ldd -rv of the executable shows both listed but not enough to figure out where they came from. We know the release version came from direct compilation and linking of the executable but we are trying to track down where the v6.6 instance got pulled in.

Trimmed down output of ldd -rv:

```
    **/devel/utililty/release/lib64/libUtils.so (0x00007f0576b29000)**
    liblog4cplus-1.1.so.9 => /lib64/liblog4cplus-1.1.so.9 (0x00007f0575fcb000)
    libsigc-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libsigc-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0575b8e000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f057479a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f057457e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0574276000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0573f73000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0573d5d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f057399a000)
    libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 => /lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f0573782000)
    libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 => /lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f057357e000)
    **libUtils.so => /devel/utility/v6.6/lib64/libUtils.so (0x00007f05730a1000)**
```